# Compiling with gradle idea

Tags: compilation, jar, gradle

Hi) when I compile the project are with *gradle idea*, I should get jar file...?
maybe in the folder *dist*... 
The problem is that I get only two files `start.sh` and `start.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

`gradle idea` doesn't compile the project. It creates project files (*.iws, *.ipr, *l.iml) for  IDEA (the IDE from JetBrains). Likewise, there is `gradle eclipse` to create project files for the Eclipse IDE.

To create a Jar, you can do `gradle jar` or `gradle build` (assuming you have the `java` plugin applied). `gradle tasks` shows which tasks are available for a given project.

Answer (score 1):

`start.sh` and `start.cmd` sound like they are coming from the `application plugin`. Are you using the application plugin?

The above poster is right that `gradle idea` simply creates the `IntelliJ` files that define your modules, src locations, etc. It does NOT compile the project.

Adding `apply plugin: 'java'` to your `build.gradle` will allow you to run `gradle jar` to generate a jar file.